# Css for dynamically adjusting the column size

Tags: jquery, html, css

Following is a html table code that I have.

```css
    .table_header
    {
     text-align: center;
     width:50px;
     vertical-align: middle;
     background-color: gainsboro;
    }
```

```html
  <table>
       <tr>
          <th class="table_header"></th>
          <th class="table_header">header 1</th>
          <th class="table_header">header 2</th>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td class="table_header">very large row header 1</td>
          <td><input class="qty_input" value="0" type="text"/></td>
          <td><input class="qty_input" value="0" type="text"/></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td class="table_header">row header 2</td>
          <td><input class="qty_input" value="0" type="text"/></td>
          <td><input class="qty_input" value="0" type="text"/></td>
       </tr>
    </table>
```

The first column correctly set to 50px. But all other columns have different size. So i provided style with width 40px for the td and input field. It partially fixed, but the problem is when the length of the row header name id large, then its height is adjusted, but the input field remains the same. I heed to get the input field also adjusted when the row header size is increased.

Input fields are used to save float values. so small width is needed otherwise the table will become bigger

Comment: Give size in % <th width="5%" >header 1</th>

Answer (score 0):

Use `thead` and `tbody`. Try this markup:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="table_header">header 1</th>
      <th class="table_header">header 2</th>
      <th class="table_header">header 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="table_header">very large row header 1</td>
      <td><input class="qty_input" value="0" type="text"/></td>
      <td><input class="qty_input" value="0" type="text"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="table_header">row header 2</td>
      <td><input class="qty_input" value="0" type="text"/></td>
      <td><input class="qty_input" value="0" type="text"/></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either provide full width to your table and then let the columns adjust as per the data provided to display.

HTML:

```
<table class="my_table">
       <tr>
          <th>header 1</th>
          <th>header 2</th>
          <th>header 3</th>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td>very large row header 1</td>
          <td><input class="qty_input" value="0" type="text"/></td>
          <td><input class="qty_input" value="0" type="text"/></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td>row header 2</td>
          <td><input class="qty_input" value="0" type="text"/></td>
          <td><input class="qty_input" value="0" type="text"/></td>
       </tr>
    </table>
```

CSS:

```
  .my_table
    {
        text-align: center;
        width:100%;
        vertical-align: middle;
        background-color: gainsboro;
    }
```